# Regex to replace duplicate characters

Tags: regex

I have a full text search and I it needs to only have a single joining characters but sometimes I receive it with multiple.

E.g.
To search for `Java Objects` the client replaces the space with a `+` So the server searches for `Server+Objects`. This is all good but sometimes a user will type `Java   Objects` and this will reach the server as `Java+++Objects` and my full text search fails.

I need to replace all the occurrences of `+++` with a single `+` keeping in mind I may get a query like `Java+++Objects++With+Names+like++++Abstract`.

I can write some code to strip them out but I know doing a regex will be cleaner but I have shamefully not spent much time learning them.

Comment: What characters should be replaced? I'm assuming this won't include letters and numbers.

Comment: What if `Java   Objects` reaches the server as `Java%20%20%20Objects`?

Comment: It was just the + character that needs replacing because the client replaces any spaces with a + but its a user entered value. The full text searching is just a postgresql full text search and there the + is used as a word separator.  So Java%20%20%20Objects will be just a single word.

Comment: My answer works for multiple instances of something like "%20" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example to replace all duplicate characters (you didn't specify a language so I'm using the perl s// operator in my example):

```
s/(.)\1+/\1/g;
```

"." in this pattern is what you are searching for. If you only want to replace duplicate, non-whitespace characters for example, use this:

```
s/(\W)\1+/\1/g;
```

See example at https://www.regex101.com/r/oL2mW5/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this pattern: `\+{2,}` which searches for 2 or more `+` signs. And replace all occurences with `+`.
https://regex101.com/r/rG7pL2/2

Comment: Or `\+\++` to confuse the one reading the regex a year from now ;-)